# Rubymine startup error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/util/lang/UrlClassLoader

Tags: java, rubymine

I am using Ubuntu 11.04, when i start RubyMine3.1 it gave this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/util/lang/UrlClassLoader
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 1 more
```

I tried every thing, i also have sun-java installed, set it default by update-java-alternatives, also my JAVA_HOME, JDK_HOME, RUBYMINE_JDK points to the sun-java directory, but still no success.

Does any one have any idea about it?

Comment: Seems like the jar containing `com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader` is not on the classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Damaged download or some classes left from older version? Try to download again and unpack into an empty directory.

Did you install any third-party plug-ins? In this case you should try to delete them from the [plugins directory](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181).

The class which fails to load is located in `RubyMine/lib/util.jar`. Maybe you are using an old version of `rubymine.sh` which doesn't add `util.jar` to the classpath?

Comment: The same download was working well. I just re-installed my OS, and afterwards this error occurs.

Comment: @Nazar, I've added a couple more possible cases to my reply.

Comment: Just removed the directory and extracted the downloaded file again and it works. Means there would be some custom plugin in plugin directory. Thanks